# Easy way to store structure pointer members within structure into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2017

I'm implementing a scheduling simulation. I'd really appreciate it if someone know me a easy way to store structure pointer variables within structure into a vector and to print out it for checking.

I Know how to put the `Input_Data` in the Array `P_LU[i].Fixture_Type[j]` as shown following. But i'd like to move the value stored in the Array `P_LU[i].Fixture_Type[j]` to the Vector.

This is a part of my simulation code.

```
/*Input_Data
3
3 1 4 4
3 1 5 1
3 1 5 1
*/

struct  Struct_Order {
int Part_No;
int Due_Date;
int Part_Type;
int Pallet;
};

struct Struct_Pallet {
int Pallet_No;
int *Fixture_Type;
Struct_Order *Part;
};



// pallets with fixture types at LU station
  P_LU = new Struct_Pallet[N_Pallet_LU];
  for (int i = 0; i < N_Pallet_LU; i++)
  {
     int N_Fixture_LU;
     fin >> N_Fixture_LU;

     P_LU[i].Pallet_No = i; 
     P_LU[i].Fixture_Type = new int[N_Fixture_LU];

        for (int j = 0; j < N_Fixture_LU; j++)
        {
           fin >> temp_fixture_type; 
           P_LU[i].Fixture_Type[j] = temp_fixture_type;
        }
}
```

======> Question. I want to put `int *Fixture_Type` `Struct_Order *Part` in `Struct_Pallet` type vector , not array.

I do not know if my intentions were delivered. Just leave me a comment if you need more explanation.

Comment: I think it would be easiest to use `std::vector` instead of all these pointers.

Comment: So i tried to do that like this... but i couldn't print out that for checking. Could you show me a simple example?
 
struct StructPallet {
int Pallet_No;
std::vector<StructFixture> Fixture_vec;
std::vector<StructOrder> Order_vec;
}

Comment: Yeah that's the way. Then you would use `emplace_back` or `push_back` to add a new element to the collection. Should simplify things for you.

Comment: i edited comment :) thanks. then how can i  print out that? is it same with vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using pointers and taking on the responsibility for tracking sizes, allocating memory, deallocating memory, etc, you can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will handle all that complexity for you:

```
#include <vector>

struct Order {
    int part_no;
    int due_date;
    int part_type;
    int pallet;
};

struct Pallet {
    int pallet_no;
    std::vector<int> fixture_types;
    std::vector<Order> parts;
};
```

Here's some sample code built using the code you have in the OP

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0OcztQRHYFZyD7qX)

```
int main()
{
    int num_pallets = 0;
    std::cin >> num_pallets;
    
    std::vector<Pallet> pallets;
    pallets.reserve(num_pallets);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pallets; ++i)
    {
        Pallet next_pallet;
        next_pallet.pallet_no = i; 
        
        int num_fixture_types = 0;
        std::cin >> num_fixture_types;
  
        next_pallet.fixture_types.reserve(num_fixture_types);
        for (int j = 0; j < num_fixture_types; j++)
        {
            int temp_fixture_type = 0;
            std::cin >> temp_fixture_type; 
            next_pallet.fixture_types.push_back(temp_fixture_type);
        }
        pallets.push_back(std::move(next_pallet));
    }
    
    for (const Pallet& next_pallet : pallets)
    {
        std::cout << "Pallet: " << next_pallet.pallet_no << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Fixture types:\n\t";
        for (int fixture_type : next_pallet.fixture_types)
            std::cout << fixture_type << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Input:

> 3 
> 3 1 4 4
> 3 1 5 1
> 3 1 5 1

Output:

```
Pallet: 0
Fixture types:
    1 4 4 
Pallet: 1
Fixture types:
    1 5 1 
Pallet: 2
Fixture types:
    1 5 1
```

Comment: AndyG I completely solved it the way you told me. This method is simple and useful for me because threre are many variables in my simulator. Your kind explanation helped me a lot. Thanks!!:)

Comment: @AngelChoi: I'm glad it helped. If my answer solved your problem, please check the green checkmark underneath the downvote button to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: AndyG i just uploaded a new question about std::vector<Order> parts. How can i insert struct Order type vector into structural vector  pallets. If you have time to spare, please look at my new question.